# Download pipeline artifact from another pipeline Azure

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-artifacts

I'm very new to this pipeline and i'm trying to build a automated way to build the `.msi` installer file for my application.

I have 2 projects `.Net Core` and `Python`, so i created 2 pipelines. The .Net Core pipeline will build and save the files in a location and Python pipeline uses those files(from location) for its dependency and builds a new `.msi` file, the last portion in the pipeline `newsetup.py` builds the `.msi` to which i'll be passing the location of the output files of .Net Core pipeline.

The error i get is `Artifact dropcli was not found for build 150.`

**.Net Core pipeline script:**

```
- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:DesktopBuildPackageLocation="$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\WebApp.zip" /p:DeployIisAppPath="Default Web Site"'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
    
- task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
  inputs:
   targetPath: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)'
   artifact: 'dropcli'
   publishLocation: 'pipeline'

- task: VSTest@2
  inputs:
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
```

**Python pipeline script:**

```
- task: DownloadPipelineArtifact@2
  inputs:
    buildType: 'current'
    artifactName: 'dropcli'
    targetPath: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)'

- task: PythonScript@0
  inputs:
    scriptSource: 'filePath'
    scriptPath: 'src/python/newsetup.py'
    arguments: 'bdist_msi $(Pipeline.Workspace)'
```

Also if i specify the build number somewhere won't it be an issue when a new pipeline is created? Or is that an limitation?

Comment: Every pipeline should use its own $(Pipeline.Workspace), so you need to use a shared folder something like $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory) or anything else to publish and download artifacts. Also add buildnumber to your artifact name..

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In your `DownloadPipelineArtifact@2` task, the value of `buildType` is `current`. This means that you are downloading the artifact in the current run. You should set `buildType` to `specific`. Here is an example to download the latest artifact from a specific pipeline:

```
- task: DownloadPipelineArtifact@2
  inputs:
    buildType: 'specific'
    project: '{project id}'
    definition: '{pipeline id}'
    buildVersionToDownload: 'latest'
    artifactName: 'dropcli'
    targetPath: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)'
```

You can click "Settings" at the top of the task, it will help you to complete your task more easily.

[image]

[image]

Click [Download Pipeline Artifacts task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/download-pipeline-artifact?view=azure-devops#arguments) for detailed information about arguments of this task.

> If i specify the build number somewhere won't it be an issue when a new pipeline is created? Or is that an limitation?

You don't need to specify the build number, and what you need to specify is the pipeline definition id. You can either download the latest artifact of a pipeline or the artifact of a specific build of a pipeline.

Comment: What even is a project, the repository name does not work for me

Comment: After running the DownloadPipelineArtifact@2 task, is it possible to copy a specific folder in the artifact to another folder?

Comment: @JoshMonreal You can try [copy files task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/copy-files-v2?view=azure-pipelines&tabs=yaml).